# How to pass *args in classytags (django)

Tags: python, django

Here I want to send a list of unknown arguments in classy tags, I have searched it on site but didn't found anything useful.

please help me out

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at MultiKeyWordArgument: http://django-classy-tags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#classytags.arguments.MultiKeywordArgument ? It sounds like what you need.

Comment: yes, i have gone through it but i can't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the given link, here it is explained properly

[django-classy-tags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/…](http://django-classy-tags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#classytags.arguments.MultiKeywordArgument)